# How to connect 2 ISPs into a single LAN?

Tags: router, internet, lan, connection, isp

I have 2 ISPs in case one fails. Ideally I would also like to take advantage of balancing LOAD on each ISP to maximize speed.

My Current Network:

- LAN A + 6 Deco M4 Mesh Router Mode (4 connected to LAN): 40+ devices (USING ISP A - 300MB symmetric - fiber)
- LAN B 15+ devices cable modem w/router function (USING ISP B - 300MB asymmetric - coaxial)

Goal:

- 1 single LAN (no connectivity issues) with Deco M4 Mesh, with 2 ISPs balancing load and providing continuity in 1 ISP if the other is down

How can I do this? do I need a special device to manage traffic other than main the Deco M4? Can I do something plug and play or I need device programming? In that case, can I buy a device and get remote support to program this?

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done? Right now you're asking us to suggest an entire solution, and it doesn't appear you've done any homework or tried anything yet.

Answer (score 1):

Most of what's on the Internet depends on HTTP, which depends on TCP.

*You cannot magically make TCP work over two separate links with their own IP address  without having something installed on both ends that implements some sort of bonding/teaming.*

*It is not possible due to the way TCP works.  TCP is a connection oriented protocol that works with a maximum of 2 sockets (IP+port), one on the sending end and one on the receiving end, no more, no less.*

*You cannot convert TCP to another protocol that could possibly work unless the other side is also working with you.*

You can definitely do a number of things on your own network, but you control those machines and can do what you want.  For example, you can put 2 NICs into two local Linux servers, connect them with crossover cables, and set up bonded interfaces to increase your throughput to >1000Mbps *between those two machines only*.

You cannot make both your ISP connections magically combine when you go to Google, for example, because you can't configure their systems.

Comment: I agree with you on the technical aspect, but disagree with how the information is presented. You can certainly load balance across two WAN connections even if a single TCP stream will never be faster than the single fastest connection. But your post makes it sound like what the OP wants to do is not possible. But load balancing and redundancy certainly is.